# Calculating the entropy of vaporization at temperatures other than the normal boiling point

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would appreciate if someone could explain why this is so:
To find the entropy of transition at another temperature, we have to break the calculation down into three steps . For example, to find the entropy of vaporization of water at 25  C and 1 bar, imagine that we
1. heat the liquid to its normal boiling point, 100 C 
2. allow it to vaporize,
3. then cool the vapor back to 25  C

Why do you do these three processes? I don't understand why this would give you the entropy of transition at another temperature...

Comment: How would you propose doing it? The answer lies at the heart of thermodynamics - it doesn't matter _how_ something gets from state A to state B, the Gibbs free energy difference is the same. So, you pick the easiest path to perform the calculation, knowing that the answer is the answer.

Comment: @jonCuster That's was my conclusion after thinking and discussing it with my friends! Thanks!